# Stop loading child collection, If I update parent

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, jhipster

**I don't want to select child collections on saving parent entity**

I have parent+child relationship and child collection is mapped as lazy. I fetch a parent, and of course because of the lazy loading child collection is not loaded. But when I want to update my parent first child collections are loading then parent is updating. Performance issue ! How to solve ?

```html
Parent entity :
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOAN")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Loan implements java.io.Serializable {

private Long id;
private Set<VchN> vchNs=new HashSet<VchN>(0);
private Set<VchN2> vchNs2=new HashSet<VchN2>(0);
.
.
.
.
private Set<VchN100> vchNs100=new HashSet<VchN100>(0);

/*
 id setter getter
*/
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "loan_id", insertable = false,updatable = false)
public Set<VchN> getVchNs() {
        return vchNs;
}

public void setVchNs(Set<VchN> vchNs) {
        this.vchNs = vchNs;
}

/*

setters getters

*/


}


Child enity:

@Entity
@Table(name = "VCH_N")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class VchN implements java.io.Serializable {

private Loan loan;
@Column(name = "loan_id", nullable = false)
public Long getLoanId() {
        return loanId;
}

public void setLoanId(Long loanId) {
        this.loanId = loanId;
}

}

so on......
```

```
Now when I execute
loanRepository.save(loan);

Output:
select columns from VchN where loan_id=?
select columns from VchN2 where loan_id=?
.
.
.
select columns from VchN100 where loan_id=?
update Loan set column = ?

I just want to update parent entity.
```

Comment: Where is your code! what have u tried so far? Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your relationship bi-directional. On your VchN entities, specify a @ManyToOne annotation on the Loan property. Remove the @JoinColumn annotation on each VchN collections property in your Loan entity. Instead, place the @JoinColumn annotation on the loan property of the VchN entity classes. Specify that Loan entity is the inverse side of the relationship by using the mappedby attribute of the @OneToMany annotation.

Sample below:

```
public class Loan implements java.io.Serializable {
...
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="loan")
public Set<VchN> getVchNs() {
        return vchNs;
}
...

public class VchN implements java.io.Serializable {
...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "loan_id")
public Loan getLoan() {
        return loan;
}
...
```

Comment: Actually, you don't have to specify the fetch type of the collection to be Lazy, since they are default lazy.